# Saving "enlarge image" with web pages

Tags: software-rec, images, webpage

I save web pages using Firefox (web page, complete) but I would like to save the "enlarge image", linked to the thumbnail as well. Is there a software that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you either want an offline browser program (i.e. a program that downloads every page and graphics and follows links and download those pages and graphics).  The other thing that may work (depending on the site) is a program like [Bulk Image Downloader (BID)](http://antibody-software.com/web/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=33).

As far as offline browsers, I like [Teleport Pro](http://tenmax.com/teleport/pro/home.htm), however, I've seen other free and cheaper applications.  These offline browsers could be restricted as to what they download or what links they follow.  Worse comes to worse, you could download the whole page/site and delete what you didn't want.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Tom, stackoverflow is for helping people with their programming problems (ie *making* software), not helping the world *use* every little bit of software. You might find this thread gets closed for that reason.

But on topic, have a look at [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)